# How To Add Block Outside of Magento_Theme?

Tags: magento2, blocks, containers

```
 <container name="container" label="header-container" as="header-container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
            <container name="header-options" label="header-options" as="header-options" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-options">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="language.select" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/language-select.phtml"></block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="distributor.search" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/distributor-search.phtml"></block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="contact.link" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/contact-link.phtml"></block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" template="Magento_Search::form-mini.phtml"></block>
            </container>
        </container>
```

Im trying to add the magento top.search into my header however I am struggling to get it to show, all other blocks within Magento_Theme are working just unable to add the Magento_Search::form-mini.phtml?

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What file did you add the code to?

Comment: this is in my default.xml in my theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is normally named form.mini.phtml not form-mini.phtml

Replace with below:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search.custom" as="topSearchcustom" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
```

Comment: No worries i always miss little things like this sometimes you just need another set of eyes.

Comment: Good spot, I compared that with the template name and missed it O.o

Comment: Me too i looked at the actual file and missed its only when i looked at the original layout i noticed.